# Remove Outlook from the Windows 10 Action Center

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-10, action-center

Windows 10 Action Center lights up whenever I receive a new Outlook mail.

Problem: I get new mails all the time, so the Action Center icon is (almost) constantly lit. Clicking on it to "clear" it is a nuisance, and I'm afraid that I might miss "important" notifications from the Action Center once I start ignoring it.

Is there a way to stop the Windows 10 Action Center from notifying me about new mails?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the Settings app, go to [System > Notifications & actions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028678/windows-10-change-notification-settings-in-action-center), find Outlook and turn off the toggle in the same row.

Personally, I found it better to let the toggle on, click the whole Outlook row and disable just the "Show notifications in action center" toggle on the page that appears. The notifications are still on, but they vanish from the Action center once the notification banner hides.

Comment: That's a great idea (leave notifications active and just disable action center), I'll try that.

Comment: The added benefit is that you don't have to wait for a notification to pop up.

Comment: This is no longer working after the most current windows update--KB4503327

Comment: It's unclear if I'll still get native Outlook notifications with this solution.  Will I?

Comment: What do you mean by native Outlook notifications, @Devil'sAdvocate? Notifications arrive in action center. If you turn off notifications completely, you won't get them. If you turn off just the Show notifications in action center as described in the second paragraph, the notifications are still displayed, they just disappear after the banner hides.

Comment: Outlook used to have native popup email notifications.  Do they still exist?  An example is Slack. You can choose to either use the Windows Notification Center or native notification popups.

Comment: Don't know if they're supported in current Outlook, @Devil'sAdvocate. This Q & A is about the notifications in Action Center. As the solution I proposed lies in changing settings of Action Center, it definitely does not influence native notifications, if there are any.

Comment: This also does not work for me: "Show notifications in action center" is off, but I still get them in the action center.

Answer (score 11):

Right-click on the "Outlook 2013" heading in the Action Center, and select "Turn off notifications for this app".

Comment: Example of obvious GUI setting which looks not really obvious.

Comment: It looks like this can only be done if there is actually a mail notification present in action centre: I just needed to send myself a mail in order to be able to right-click on that mail notification in the action centre and remove it and change the corresponding configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable those notifications in Outlook itself. Currently, in Outlook 365, it's under "File" > "Options" > "Mail", section "Message arrival", option "Display a Desktop Alert".