# Add Outlook 2013 mail to Windows 10 Action Center and Lock Screen

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-10, lock-screen, action-center

The inverse of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/949794/remove-outlook-from-the-windows-10-action-center): How do I get new mail from Outlook 2013 to show up in Action Center and Lock Screen on Windows 10? The "Microsoft Outlook" and "Outlook 2013" toggles are on in the "Notifications & Actions" setting screen, but I don't see new mail in Notification center. I wonder if the two entries cause a problem. The tray icon's "Show new mail desktop alert" is also checked.

Comment: Weird. I have W10 and Outlook 2013. It works for me out of the box. If the Outlook window is open, the new mail notification shows up in Action /Notification panel.

Comment: I was able to fix this; I'll be able to post screenshots tomorrow when I have my PC on.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that I log in using a Microsoft account, so my outlook.com account is all over the place, but my office Exchange account only lives within Outlook?

Comment: I just noticed that Outlook shows a banner and notification center lights up when new mail arrives, but the action center un-highlights almost immediately. Another mail just came in and appears in action center if I click while the banner is still on the desktop. Click away and close action center clears the notification.

Comment: I just verified the email's Desktop Banner clears the message from the Action Center when the banner closes. To fix this, go to **Notifications & actions**, click **OUTLOOK 2013**, and turn off **Show notification banners**.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the Settings app
2. Go to System

[image]

3. Go to Notifications & actions and scroll down to find "Show notifications from these apps"

[image]

4. Click on Outlook 2013
5. Enable notifications and notification banners

[image]