# How to remove Windows 10 notification handling and still receive notifications from applications

Tags: windows-10, notifications

Most answers to the question "How to disable Action Center (AC)" assume you want to disable notifications as well, but what I'd like to do is make Windows work like the AC doesn't exist, so I would still continue to receive notifications, but in the native format and on the schedule decided by each application individually.

For instance, I would like to see the Outlook original "toasters" when new emails are received that I used to see before AC was introduced.

I could not find any way to do this, even after submitting the question to Microsoft. I tried various ways of disabling the AC but they either stop notifications as well or just hide the icon or action center without changing its behavior.

The reason for this is I find AC behavior very unproductive and quite annoying at times: notifications stop at random times for no apparent reason (unrelated to Focus Assist settings), past notifications start showing one by one with no obvious way to stop them etc.

Comment: I don't even believe the action center can be disabled.  You can disable notifications, but not every notification, what you want would require a third-party software.  If software exists to change the behavior of the action center I couldn't say, if you are not a fan of the action center, you might have to downgrade to an earlier version of Windows or accept the action center and disable notifications.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the Action Center:

- Right-click the Taskbar and select Taskbar Settings
- Scroll down and click on "Turn system icons on or off"
- Set the "Action Center" item slider to Off
- This immediately removes Action Center icon from the Taskbar, while
  notifications are not affected.

For testing if notifications are still working, you could install the
Notifications Visualizer from the Microsoft Store.
When running it, click New document. The Pop toast button will create a new
notification each time that it is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it's not what I want - it's true that the AC icon doesn't show anymore but notifications are still handled by AC internally with the same issues as before, .

Comment: What are these issues?

Comment: As I described in my original post, the most annoying is that notifications don't have a predictable and consistent behavior, and I'm talking mostly about Outlook new email notifications. Sometimes new emails trigger a visible notification, other times they don't (unrelated to Focus Assist which is disabled). Also, at times all accumulated notifications start showing up one after another until they are all gone, each with the associated sound.

Comment: This becomes Outlook-specific. Questions: (1) Which Outlook version? (2) Are the missing alerts for specific non-Inbox folders?  First check: Is Outlook ticked in *Settings > System > Notifications & Actions*? You could also try to repair Microsoft Office in Programs and Features. See also [useful link](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/newmailalert.htm).

Comment: This is not an Outlook issue - new email notifications are received by the Action Center (I can see them listed if if I open the AC) but they don't trigger the AC toasters. Outlook notifications used to work fine before they introduced the AC.

Comment: It's possibly an interface problem between Outlook and Windows. If you want us to continue, please follow my last comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "follow my last comment"?

Comment: Yesterday's comment. 4th comment above from this one.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to get my head around (and it sounds like you do, too) was that that horrible "action centre" now *is* the native notification system in Win 10.

So you simply won't get the "original Outlook toasters" anymore with action centre around. In other words, I don't think you can do what you want anymore (unless you roll back to pre-action centre times).

For Outlook notifications to not bug me in the action centre, I found [this related answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334308/109305) very helpful. I now get a notification when an email arrives (from the action centre), and the icon on the very bottom right shows an item in it (which still bugs me), but it disappears as soon as the notification does. And I can click on the notification to open the email if I want to.